# The meaning of budding technology

Tags: keyless-entry, technology

could someone help me understand what a budding technology is? Budding usually means "being in an early developmental stage", but I don't think this definition applies in this context. Thank you!

"[RKS largely and quickly superseded keyless entry, a budding technology that restrictively bound locking and locking functions to vehicle-mounted keypads.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_keyless_system)"

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. In the sense of the article, *budding* in this sense is what the the product (keyless entry) was at the time of its introduction ... which *all technology is* at the time of introduction.
2. You're looking at Wikipedia, which is user fed. This means "stuff" in there can be either old or at the whim of whoever put the information in there. The "author" of that tidbit thought it was probably a good word to use.

IMHO, this is an ignorant way to write what they are trying to say. By putting it in there, the author is being redundant. We know it was a budding technology at the time of introduction. It definitely isn't now, so all you are doing is confusing the reader. Most likely, whoever wrote it was trying to use crafty words to write something simple.